# Undefined method error with public-activity gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to implement the public-activity gem into my Rails app. I'm following along with the excellent Railscast episode (http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity) but I've run into the following error when I run localhost:3000/activities:

NoMethodError in Activities#index
undefined method `content' for #

The error shows that the issue lies in the views/activities/index.html.erb file:

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
    <div class ="activity">
         <%= link_to activity.owner.content, activity.owner if activity.owner %>
          <%= render_activity activity %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
```

It doesn't seem to like the "link_to activity.owner.content" bit on the third line.

Activities controller:

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(owner_id: current_user.followed_users.all, owner_type: "User")
  end
end
```

Content is a column in my posts table. I'm trying to track/show the activity of users that a particular user may follow. Does my issue reside in one of the files above or is the issue somewhere else?

If it helps, if I replace the index.html.erb view with

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <%= activity.inspect %>
<% end %>
```

I can see the raw data displayed on the page with no errors. The error appears once I replace the inspect code with the new code mentioned earlier. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Additional information: I'm using Devise for user authentication and I'm using the follower system as seen in Michael Hartl's Railstutorial sample app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

does youur owner model have, content attribute?

The railcast says

```
<%= link_to activity.owner**.name**, activity.owner if activity.owner %>
```

instead of

```
<%= link_to activity.owner.content, activity.owner if activity.owner %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is no owner model so this is the part I'm getting stuck on. He uses .name because there is a name attribute in his recipe model, so I thought I could switch it with my content attribute from my post model.

Comment: are you using devise. that would have have created the user model, which gives current_user, which is user as owner_id.

Comment: Yes I'm using devise. I want to show activity for users that current_user follows so I set owner_ id to current_user.followed_users . Do I need to change it to just current_user?

Comment: Even if I change it to owner.name I still get the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: remove the whole line. You need to check your models. and use the ones that are relevant.